# Android Signature verification of PKCS#1 PSS (RSASSA-PKCS) not working with algorithm SHA256withRSA

Tags: android, signing

Im developing an mobile application which has to verify some signatures that it has received. I have got everything that i need - the input data, public key and the signature. But there is a problem. Im using the method SHA256withRSA for signature verifiation which contains this few lines of code to verify the signature:

```
    Signature sg = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
    sg.initVerify(pubKey);
    sg.update(input);
    return sg.verify(sign);
```

But i noticed that this only works for PKCS1_v1.5, but the used signature schema for which it has to work is PKCS#1 PSS and therefore it returns always false. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem not with verifying but with signing. The only solution I found was using the BouncyCastleProvider. To use RSASSA-PSS-Sign/-Verify you need to set "algorithm" to SHA256withRSA/PSS not SHA256withRSA. This algorithm is not provided by default.